# After I enable APC our pages do not load

Tags: php, apache, apc

I have installed APC on our Windows dev server. After I enable APC and restart apache our pages do not load. They timeout and I just get connection was reset on browser or automatic stopping apache service.

```
System              Windows NT 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Server Edition Service Pack 1) i586 
Architecture        x86 
Server API          Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
Thread Safety       enabled
PHP Extension Build API20100525,TS,VC9


Apache Version      Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 
Virtual Server      Yes
```

APC Runtime Settings

```
extension=php_apc_319_php54_vc9_win7-2008.dll

[APC]
; Enable/disable APC
apc.enabled = 1

; PHP file cache 1 hour
apc.ttl=3600

; User cache 2 hour
apc.user_ttl=7200

; Garbage collection 1 hour
apc.gc_ttl=3600

; Setting this to 0 will give you the best performance, as APC will
; not have to check the IO for changes.
apc.stat=1
```

download the APC precompiled binary version from 
http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html

I also checked php error log and I do not see anything there.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) running?

Comment: nope... not have suPHP

Comment: I can only think of a setting not being correct in your php.ini. Check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) for more info on this...

Comment: I also tried a minimal configuration apc.enabled=1 apc.stat=1 same result

Comment: Is there a Cpanel or DirectAdmin with auto build to overwrite certain settings?